# What is the practical probability of a bit getting flipped during transmission?

Tags: signal-processing, error, error-correction

We know that Coding Theory depends on the fact that the probability `p` of a bit flip must be less than `0.5`. From [*Fundamentals of Error-Correcting Codes (pg.39)*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=B2FjPXtS_QUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q=in%20most%20practical&f=false), it states

> In most practical situations `p` is very small.

Using the technology we have in 2020 such as Fiber-optic cable, other types of cables, or wireless medium, what is the practical probability a bit encountering a flip during transmission?

Comment: Bits don't flip; it's noise added to the signal that cons the receiver into believing it received a 1 when it was a zero (or vice versa). A different receiver placed several miles away in a different direction may not witness any error therefore, you cannot say that a bit has flipped during transmission else it would affect both receivers i.e. it's a local phenomenon. So, the probability is down to how much noise is present and how good the receiver is at distinguishing an error free bit over the symbol duration period.

Comment: It depends on the system. For example a music CD can tolerate some manufacturing imperfections due to ECC, but it will also tolerate degrading media such as scratches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fiber optic communications the design point is frequently taken as an error rate of 1 in 10**12 bits.

For wired links such as ethernet the raw bit rate is approximately 1 in 10**14.

[Error rates and testability](https://www.ieee802.org/3/efm/public/may03/optics/dawe_optics_1_0503.pdf)

[WHAT IS BER (BIT ERROR RATIO)](https://www.fiberoptics4sale.com/blogs/archive-posts/95047174-what-is-ber-bit-error-ratio-and-bert-bit-error-ratio-tester)

Comment: As a point of comparison, some 100 Gb Ethernet protocols have a maximum BER of $10^{-5}$, and user error correction codes to achieve a lower system BER.

Answer (score 2):

Bit Errors depend on

- sampling jitter (phase noise)
- squareness of the dataeye
- deterministic and random amplitude noise
- appropriate thresholding
- whether Noise is measured in BitRate bandwidth, or in HalfBitRate bandwidth

From my bit_synchronizer work of decades ago, for NRZ data, once out past 16dB SNR, the BER is dropping over a decade per dB ----- unless there is significant timing jitter.

Comment: I agree but the slope above 16dB depends on the compression ratio of bits/baud and other factors and whether the noise is Gaussian or not.  On @Kevin's example WHAT IS... it appears to be 0.5 dB per decade above 20 dB SNR. https://i.stack.imgur.com/leuq9.png  With FEC or ECC it becomes steeper and almost brick wall e,g,--75 to -70dBm for 11Mbps practically error free on WiFi while -80 dBm is almost unusable. with a 1 mm change in direction of the laptop. from Ricean fading can make this difference.  but +1 anyways.